# how to embed ssrs fetchxml dynamics 365 report in Web Page?

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, fetchxml

We have a requirement where we have to embed our Dynamics 365 fetch XML SSRS report in the web portal? please suggest how can we achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an iFram and put the link of the report in its source

```
 <iframe width="430" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" src="http://ReportManagerURL/reports/?rs:Embed=true"></iframe>
```

Comment: For this way, isn't we need to Login on to the Dynamics CRM to run that report? and there can be multiple logins on the same portal with different data.